# ALTER INDEX x REBUILD with Spring Data Repository by Oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle

Is it possible to rebuild the oracle index from Spring Data Repository with nativeQuery?

try:

```
@Repository
public interface PageDao extends CrudRepository<Page, String> {

    @Query(value = "ALTER INDEX the_native_index_name REBUILD", nativeQuery = true)
    String updateOracleTextIndex();

}
```

error:

...

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01003: no statement parsed

Comment: Why are you trying to do that from a repository? That doesn't sound like the sort of thing you should be doing with any frequency. Do you not trust Oracle to index correctly?

Comment: in this use case we have irregular imports from file system, with many commits. After the whole import the index should be rebuild. fyi that is oracle-text index.

Comment: Importing what? If you're not turning off table constraints or indexing, you shouldn't need to reindex. If you are, then you have a whole lot more complicated setup and you should be handling it (1) manually, not through Spring Data and (2) very carefully to avoid live access while inconsistent.

Comment: import from xml files. and the index should be rebuild manually, every time after import of data. And it would be nice to make it with just call repository mehtode, but ...